# Imageview drawable broken image

Tags: android, image, android-imageview, android-drawable

I'm trying to change the image of an Imageview at runtime in my Widget-App. I've got already an image, as default, in there. But if I try to change it, it won't be displayed correctly. I used this code:

```
views.setImageViewResource(R.id.btnShowCalendar, R.drawable.smsgrey);
```

The image should look like this:

[image]

But it'll be displayed as:

[image]

The white image is the old, default, one. I don't know why it doesn't replace the old image and why it does not display correctly.

Comment: check if you have set the image to image view using android:background and now you are trying to set image using imageview.setImageViewResource() which will show both the images to your Image view

Comment: Thanks. Is working now. I'm setting the second image now with views.setInt(R.id.btnShowMail, "setBackgroundResource", R.drawable.gmailgrey); and it works fine :)